# Ingress controller name for the ingress class

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting up my ingress controller, ingress class and ingress to expose a service outside the cluster. This is fresh cluster setup.

I have setup the nginx-ingress controller using

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.41.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml`

The next step based on my understanding is to create the ingress class https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: external-lb
spec:
  controller: example.com/ingress-controller
  parameters:
    apiGroup: k8s.example.com/v1alpha
    kind: IngressParameters
    name: external-lb
```

**How did they get the name of the controller `example.com/ingress-controller`?**

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to achieve? You have 2 Ingress Controllers like Nginx Ingress and GCE Ingress, and want to force this specific ingress to use one of them, or you want to create new one Ingress?

Comment: new one, freah cluster

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have run multiple scenarios with `IngressClass`, `Ingress` and `Nginx Ingress Controller`.

**Scenario 1**

- IngressClass with custom name
- Nginx Ingress Controller with default `--ingress-class` value which is `nginx`
- Ingress using ingressClassName same as IngressClass name

*Output: Response 404*

**Scenario 2**

- IngressClass with custom name
- Nginx Ingress Controller with own`ingress-class` ingress-test
- Ingress using ingressClassName same as IngressClass name

*Output: Response 404*

**Scenario 3**

- IngressClass with `test` name
- Nginx Ingress Controller `--ingress-class` with value `test`
- Ingress using `test` in ingressClassName

*Output: Proper response*

**Senario 4**

- IngressClass with `nginx` name
- Nginx Ingress Controller `--ingress-class` with value `nginx`
- Ingress using `nginx` in ingressClassName

*Output: Proper response*

**Conclusion**

First of all, please keep in mind that there are 3 types of `Nginx`. `Open Source Nginx Ingress Controller`, you are probably using it. `Nginx Incorporaton` (nginx inc) and `Nginx Incorporaton Plus`.

In one of the scenarios, when I have used `spec.controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller` with `Nginx Ingress Controller` with argument `--ingress-class=nginx`, in `Nginx Ingress Controller` pod you will see entry which is pointing to `k8s.io/ingress-nginx`.

To reproduce this behavior, you will need to deploy `IngressClass` with specific controller and then deploy nginx.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller
```

After deploying `Nginx Ingress Controller`, controller pod will be in `CrashLoopBackOff` state. In logs you will find entry:

```
E1118 15:42:19.008911       8 main.go:134] Invalid IngressClass (Spec.Controller) value "nginx.org/ingress-controller". Should be "k8s.io/ingress-nginx"
```

**It works only when `IngressClass` name is set to `nginx`.**

I would say that `nginx.org/ingress-controller` is for `Nginx Incorporated` and `k8s.io/ingress-nginx` for `Open Source Nginx Ingress`.

If custom value is used for `--ingress-class` argument in the `controller Deployment manifest`, presence or absence of `IngressClass` object with the same name doesn't made any difference in, how the cluster works, if only you keep Ingress `spec.ingressClass` value  the same with controller argument. Moreover, if it's present, IngressClass `spec.controller` can have any value that match the required pattern "domain like" and that didn't affect `Ingress` workflow behavior on my cluster at all.

In addition, `Ingress` works fine if I put the correct value of the `ingress-class` either to `spec.ingressClass` property or to `metadata.annotation.kubernetes.io/ingress.class` accordingly. It gives an error like the following if you try to put both values to the same Ingres object:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

`The Ingress "test-ingress" is invalid: annotations.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: Invalid value: "nginx": can not be set when the class field is also set`

Please keep in mind it was tested only for [Nginx Ingress Controlle](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). If you would like to use `IngressClass` with other `Ingress Controllers` like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) or [Ambasador](https://www.getambassador.io/), you would check their release notes.

Comment: I guess the answer is, there's no easy way to know the controller name to use in the `Ingressclass`, you'll have to find it in the controller's documentation or dig through the code. And even when looking in the code, there's no standard/obvious way of finding it. Nginx: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/internal/k8s/main.go#L135 aws alb: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/da8951f80521651e0a1ffe1361c011d6baad7706/pkg/ingress/class_loader.go#L20

Comment: thank you posting this detailed answer. Was facing this issue whole day, changed the name of ingressClass to nginx and it works!

Answer (score 5):

You will create the `IngressClass` as part of the `Installation with Manifests` steps (Step 2, part 3 [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/#create-common-resources)). That will create an `IngressClass` that looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
  # annotations:
  #   ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller
```

Then, to configure an `Ingress` resource to be consumed by `nginx`, just specify `ingressClassName: nginx` in the `Ingress` spec, as shown [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/#new-features-available-in-kubernetes-1-18-and-above), and pasted again below:

```yaml
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: cafe-ingress
  spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - cafe.example.com
      secretName: cafe-secret
    rules:
    - host: cafe.example.com
  . . .
```

Comment: where did you get the nginx.org/ingress-controller?

Comment: That's predefined in their installation config. Their controller will be looking for an IngressClass with that name