# What ties Ingress and Ingress Controller together?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

In kubernetes, if I have a ingress resource below, how does it know what type of Ingress Controller or which Ingress Controller (if I have multiple) to use?

> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 kind: Ingress metadata: name:
> test-ingress spec:  rules:
>
> - http:
>   paths:
>
>   - path: /testpath
>     backend:
>     serviceName: test
>     servicePort: 80 "

Comment: They are tied by 'ingress class' concept. Each ingress controller is defined by its 'class', and each ingress rule may be marked with corresponding `ingress.class` annotation. Also you may set a default ingress class in you cluster, then ingress rules without class annotations will assume this default class.

Comment: Ingress Class 
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-ingress-class

Comment: Relation thru annotations https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#using-multiple-ingress-controllers

Comment: @OlesyaBolobova Could you please post these comments as an answer? This is correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

They are tied by [ingress class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#using-multiple-ingress-controllers) concept.
Each ingress controller is defined by some IngressClass.

In a nutshell [IngressClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#ingressclassspec-v1-networking-k8s-io) is a simple wrapper object, which contains:

- mandatory `controller` field which is a pointer to actual ingress controller binary,
- optional `parameters` field for additional configuration.

Typically you would use predefined IngressClasses shipped with standard controllers, but nothing prevents you to [define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64781320/ingress-controller-name-for-the-ingress-class) your own (though it's rarely needed in practice).

Each ingress rule may be marked with corresponding `ingress.class` annotation.
E. g. `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

Also you may set a [default ingress class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-ingress-class) in you cluster.
In this case ingress rules without class annotations will assume this default class.